# HTML5 <main> tag VS2013

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013

I have decided to try and make my HTML as semantic as possible, adhering to the HTML5 guidelines, and in my new MVC5 project within VS2013 have used the    tags and so forth, however the  tag is not recognized by VS and brings an error.

I have done searching but nothing seems to exist, is the  tag not that important or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe because it's not supported by IE: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Answer (score 0):

Stated by Microsoft:

> Thank you for passing along this issue to us. We evaluate all the
>   feedback our customers submit, but unfortunately we cannot fix every
>   item that comes in. We have evaluated the issue you submitted, and at
>   this point, we do not anticipate releasing an update for it. If the
>   issue is blocking you from using the product, please contact our
>   support via the Visual Studio Help and Support
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc136615.aspx) page on MSDN.

See [Bugtracker](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806646/vs2013-html5-validation-element-main-is-not-supported)